# Visual Studio 2010/Resharper - Intellisense by Class?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, intellisense

I have an **Animal** class which my **Cat** class inherits.

When I hover over a cat instance or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to see a full list, I wish to see only cat methods and properties first, then animal ones after instead of all properties and methods in one big alphabetical list.

MonoDevelop does this with a second <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> key press and is very handy.

Does Visual Studio 2010 or Resharper have this type of capability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 does not support such functionality. Anyway, since 2008 it is a big improvement that you do not need to type the name starting from its beginning.... ;-)

As far as I know, resharper does not have exactly the same mode too. However it is far more intelligent and configurable. There are also different key combination you can use for different types of completion.

You can read more about Code Assistance features [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html)

Anyway, check the trial version before buying to be sure that it suits you. You can check also  other comprehensive extensions like CodeRush Pro, etc.

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper displays Cat's members in **bold** font and inherited members in regular font. So you see the difference.

[image]